# Passing a variable inside of a function to another Python file

Tags: python, variables

I have a two python files which are `classification_model.py` and `result.py`. There is a function in `classification_model.py` file as

```
def learningbased():
    ann_accuracy = (metrics.accuracy_score(expected, predicted))
```

I want to get this `ann_accuracy` variable into `result.py` file.I used

```
from classification_model import *
from classification_model import learningbased
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how can I do this.

Comment: Its not possible to access this way. either make it a class and add `ann_accuracy` as class variable or simply make this as a return value of function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good way:
You can return the value of ann_accuracy in the function and call the function in result.py to get the value.

```
#classification_model.py:
def learningbased():
    ann_accuracy = (metrics.accuracy_score(expected, predicted))
    return ann_accuracy

#result.py
from classification_model import *
ann_accuracy = learningbased()
```

alternate way (use when desparate, no other solution):
declare ann_accuracy as a global variable in classification_model.py. That way when you do `from classification_model import *` and call the function, you'll get the global variable in result.py

Comment: Please do NOT such suggest such an horrible thing as using a global, specially to someone who is obviously not yet able to understand why it's definitly not a good idea.

Comment: Even as reworded it's still wrong - there's ALWAYS another (better) solution. Oh and yes while we're at it : using a global and star import together will just not work (try by yourself...).

Comment: I return the ann_accuracy from the function and get it into result.py file as you said. Now its work. Thank you

Comment: The reason why I wrote the alternate solution is for the user to know that using GLOBALS is not a good idea. Knowledge is power.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should declare your project as a package, by adding a `__init__.py` file :

```
project_folder
    |_ __init__.py
    |_ classification_model.py
    |_ result.py
```

After doing that, in `result.py` you can do :

```
from . import classification_model
classification_model.learning_based()
```

It's a little different from what was already suggested and it enables you to have a clear organisation of your project.

Answer (score -2):

Declare ann_accuracy as a global variable in classification_model.py. Use `from classification_model import *`, you can use/access the global variable in result.py.

Comment: Worst solution ever, if I could downvote this answer 999 times I'd happily do. DO NOT USE GLOBALS.